# matching space character regex

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

Well I have few files with series of contents in following format:

```
[abc]           #4  *5
[pqr]           #3  *4
[xyx]           #5  *2
```

Now I needed to replace all occurance of

```
[xyx]          #3  *2
```

by

```
[xyx]          #1  *2
```

in all the files.

Now the question which is causing pain is the presence of space between [xyz] and #3. There are two thing I'm taking this search expression as command line argument in a script which looks like this:

```
searchExp=$1
repalaceExp=$2

echo $searchExp
echo $replaceExp

for i in `grep \'$searchExp\'` 
do
 sed 's/$searchExp/$replaceExp' $i > $i.new
done
```

I guess this should be fine given that I'm passing argument as:

```
./replace_script '^\[xyz\]          #3' '\[xyz\]          #1'
```

Now as you see the echo statment int the script reduces all the spaces in the search and relace expression to a single space

```
\[xyz\] #3
```

Now I tried few other alternative to take care of space character

```
 1.   ^\[xyz\][ ]+#3
```

This is one is screaming that unbalanced [ ],so regex error

```
 2. ^\[xyz\]\s+#3 //as per few suggestion on SO
```

This does'nt matches.

Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Edit:Corrected Typo

Comment: The space can be matched by `[:space:]`

Answer (score 4):

A better way would be to use a regular expression with a back reference like this:

```
searchExp='\(\[xyx\][[:space:]]*\)#5'
replaceExp='\1#1'
sed "s/$searchExp/$replaceExp/" <<%EOF%
[abc]           #4  *5
[pqr]           #3  *4
[xyx]           #5  *2
%EOF%
[abc]           #4  *5
[pqr]           #3  *4
[xyx]           #1  *2
```

Note too that you need double quotes for variables to be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` always reduces spaces so don't count on its output.

What you are really missing is that this:

```
sed 's/searchExp/replaceExp' $i > $i.new
```

should in fact be

```
sed "s/$searchExp/$replaceExp/" $i > $i.new
```

If you want to make sure you actually matched the lines, you can write the `echo` (or better, `printf`) inside the `for` loop.

Finally, if you want to use `sed` on all files and replace **in-place**, you can write like this:

```
searchExp=$1
repalaceExp=$2

sed -i "s/$searchExp/$replaceExp/" *
```

Comment: oops! It was a typo. I am using sed 's/$searchExp/$replaceExp/'. I rectified this in question.Thanks though!

Comment: Also for your doubt what I'm trying to do by $i>$i.new is that sed by default dont don inplace replacement rather prints on std o/p and I'm trying to capture it in a new file.Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Variables aren't expanded withing single quotes, you need double ones.

Comment: @mawia, `-i` takes care of that for you. If you use `i.new`, it will backup the files also. See the manual for `sed`.

Comment: Beware that `-i` is a Gnu extension so might not be available.

Comment: `echo` only reduces spaces when you don't quote the arguments. @jlliagre: `-i` is supported by some other versions of `sed` such as that for OS X.